# Google Apps Script: Calling a function from menu with a spreadsheet range as the parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, menu

I have a function that accepts a spreadsheet range as a parameter, then adds a date in the same row as the given range.

```
function autoDate(cell) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var currentDateStr = new String();
  currentDateStr = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + currentMonth;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (cell.getValue() == ""){
    var activeRowInt = cell.getRow();
    var dateCell = sheet.getRange(activeRowInt,3); //3 is my date column
    dateCell.setValue(currentDateStr);
  }
}
```

I have a menu where I run a separate function that calls autoDate() with the active cell as the parameter (since the menu system doesn't allow calling functions with parameters)

```
function autoDateMenu(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  autoDate(activeCell);
}
```

If I run autoDateMenu() from within the script editor, it works fine.
If I run autoDateMenu() by selecting it from the menu of the spreadsheet, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of undefined. (line 64, file
>   "Code")

Line 64 refers to this line:

```
if (cell.getValue() == ""){
```

Here's the code I wrote for the menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  },{
    name : "Set Date",
    functionName : "autoDateMenu"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Center", entries);
}
```

Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this? I think you are having issues with references that this would solve.

Menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  },{
    name : "Set Date",
    functionName : "autoDate"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Center", entries);
}
```

AutoDate function:

```
function autoDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var currentDateStr = new String();
  currentDateStr = currentDate.getDate() + "/" + currentMonth;

  if (activeCell.getValue() == ""){
    var activeRowInt = cell.getRow();
    var dateCell = sheet.getRange(activeRowInt,3); //3 is my date column
    dateCell.setValue(currentDateStr);
  }
}
```

Remove the middle man AutoDateMenu function.

If this does not work for your purposes we can try something else.

Comment: Hi nwill! Thanks for answering. This was actually how I wrote it initially, but then I also want to call the function with an onEdit trigger. If I do it the way you described, then I'd need a separate function for onEdit. I'd prefer to find the root problem regarding the references, but would you suggest that instead?

Comment: Well. Oddest thing. I go back to your original code to find a fix for the reference issue and cannot seem to reproduce it. I could before. Now it works fine for me.